# issues on launching chrome while running appium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

My chrome is launching in android and restarting itself multiple times but still no tests are running.
My code was earlier working 100% fine. i **just updated my chrome** in playstore and my codes are not working

Comment: capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");
   driver = new  AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
   driver.get("http://google.com");
   driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("appium");

Answer (score 0):

Check your ChromeDriver version to have the latest, because I had the same issue as you do and it was because of my previous ChromeDriver version did not support chrome under version 53.1. The symptom was the same, that Chrome started and restarted in an endless loop.

Also you should check you appium command line log, what is says to you during the test run.